# Random walk 2d average time to hit line

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Given a 2D random walk (in a lattice grid) starting from the origin what is the average waiting time to hit the line $y=1-x$

From my knowledge every point in a 2D random walk has probability one of being traversed in the walk, but trying this problem numerically seems like the expectation is unbounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X_n)$ be the random walk, and $(Y_n)$ the (signed) vertical displacement between $(X_n)$ and the line $y=1-x$, i.e. if $X_n=(x,y)$ then $Y_n=1-x-y$.

Observe that $Y_0=1$, and
$$Y_{n+1} = 
\begin{cases}
Y_n+1 & \text{with probability } 1/2, \\
Y_n-1 & \text{with probability } 1/2,
\end{cases}$$
So $(Y_n)$ is a simple random walk on $\mathbb Z$. Can you find the expected time for $(Y_n)$ to hit $0$?

Comment: Therefore since a simple random walk is null recurrent my expectation is infinite!